# SwiftUI beta 7: Trigger `List` to scroll when item added?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

#### Using Xcode 11 beta 7 and Catalina beta `19A536g` (6?)

In my SwiftUI app I have a simple view with a list. Below the list I have a button to add items to the list.

After having added some items, the newly added items are not visible, since they are outside the content size of the list.

```swift
var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
    VStack {
      List(self.accounts) { account in
        Text("\(account.name)")
      }

      Button("Add new account") {
        self.addNewAccount()
      }
    }.navigationBarTitle("Select account")
  }
}
```

I guess I would like some binding the content offset of the list, passed to my method `addNewAccount` and trigger a scrolling of the list.

### Can I somehow programmatically trigger the list to scroll down to the new content?

Comment: I remember this question's being asked before. A search on "[swiftui] list scroll" turned this up - since the answer wasn't accepted, it may be of help - and if it doesn't help, it may be that it's currently not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258846/how-to-make-a-swiftui-list-scroll-automatically

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to achieve it is to flip the list and its content using `.scaleEffect(x: 1, y: -1, anchor: .center)` in order to have an upside down structured list but with the correct looking content therefore, insertion of item at index 0 in the list will be performed at the bottom with a nice looking animation

```
List {
   ForEach(self.content) { itemContent in
       Item(itemContent).scaleEffect(x: 1, y: -1, anchor: .center)   
   }
}.scaleEffect(x: 1, y: -1, anchor: .center)
```