# How to make button visible in scrollview if it's related textfield has been focused

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` which contains `VStack` which contains a large amount of entries. The amount is not important it is just that you have to scroll to get to a `TextField` at the end of the list. Below the text field is a "submit"-`Button`.

If the user taps on the text field, the scrollview will adjust its scrolling position to make the textfield visible. But I need, that the button below the input becomes visible, too.

Does someone have any idea how I could achieve this behavior?

Thanks!

**Abstract code**

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {

        // ... content

        // Button aera
        VStack {
            Text("Text")
            
            Button("Action Text") {
                onSubmitRequested()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your button in VStack along with TextFields?

Comment: I suppose [this is the answer you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67730429/10876104). The answerer has described the issue pretty well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution - based on `scrollTo`, focused state, and animation alignment, latter is important, because focused state update happens much earlier than keyboard appears.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Main part:

```
        TextField("Placeholder", text: $text)
            .focused($focused)
        Button("Submit") { }
            .padding()    // << for better visibility
            .id("submit")
    }
}
.onChange(of: focused) {
    if $0 {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {    // << !!
            withAnimation {  // << same default animation
                sr.scrollTo("submit", anchor: .bottom)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestTextFieldWButtonKeyboard.swift)