# How to show words once at a time in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, swiftui

I have an array of string and of course when the view appears, the ForEach shows all the items at once, but I would like to show one item at a time, i think i should do it using an animation but i don't know how to go on...

##### This is the effect i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

##### This is my simple code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let correctNames = ["Steve", "Bill", "Elon", "Paul"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(correctNames, id: \.self) { name in
                Text("\(name)")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so how many accounts do you have? I saw previous post, just in case. ;)

Comment: @Asperi Isn't it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple approach.

Use a timer and a counter. Increment the counter every second and show the items 0 to counter animated. If the counter reaches the size of the array cancel the timer.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let correctNames = ["Steve", "Bill", "Elon", "Paul"]
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var counter = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0...counter, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(correctNames[index])
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
            }
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            withAnimation {
                if counter < correctNames.count - 1 {
                    counter = counter + 1
                } else {
                    timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different take.  Use `.opacity()` to hide/show the names, and give each view an increasing `delay`.  When `animating` is toggled with `onAppear`, the views will show one by one.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var animating = false
    let correctNames = ["Steve", "Bill", "Elon", "Paul"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<correctNames.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Text("\(correctNames[index])")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .opacity(animating ? 1 : 0)
                    .animation(.default.delay(Double(index)), value: animating)
            }
        }
        .onAppear { animating.toggle() }
    }
}
```

If you want to make the fade in longer, replace the `.animation()` line with:

```
.animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.9).delay(Double(index)), value: animating)
```

To increase or decrease the time between names, multiply `Double(index)` by the number of seconds you want.

Comment: The animation is actually clean, thank you!

Comment: If I don't bother you, do you have any idea on how i can insert these words in a ScrollView and make it scroll automatically when showing a new word?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/58376681/1630618