# SwiftUI List - How to scroll to item

Tags: swiftui

I have list with items. How can i scroll to list 12. I can use geometry reader to calculate offset. But how to scroll to this offset?

```
List {
      ForEach(0..<12) { index in
          Text("...")          
      }  
}
```

Comment: If your app design allows to use ScrollView instead of List, you can consider approach demonstrated in [How to make a SwiftUI List scroll automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258846/how-to-make-a-swiftui-list-scroll-automatically/58708206#58708206) post.

Answer (score 6):

Form **Xcode 12**, You can turn in to a `ScrollView` and then you can do it by `.scrollTo(id)`:

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
        ScrollView {
            ForEach((1...100), id: \.self) { Text("\($0)") }
        }
        Button("Go!") {
            withAnimation { scrollProxy.scrollTo(50) }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note that** `ScrollViewReader` should support all scrollable content, but now it only supports `ScrollView`

Comment: I just tried in XCode 13 on macOS 12 and `ScrollViewReader` now works with `List`.