# SwiftUI: ScrollView Offset Scroll Content

Tags: ios, scrollview, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a ScrollView using SwiftUI that contains an HStack and ForEach() of calendar objects to scroll through back and forth to select a date to mimic below:

[image]

The array of dates would be say 30 days in the past of today's date  and 30 days in the future. When I initialize the ScrollView, it always starts on the 30th day in the past (Array index 0) but how could I offset the scroll of the ScrollView to where today's date is centered in the view? I've tried using `.content.offset(x: offset)` but it physically offsets the location of the scroll in the view, not the amount scrolled.

```
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {

            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: self.spacing) {

                ForEach(self.dateArray, id: \.self) { date in
                    CalendarObject(date: date)
                }
            }
        }
        .content.offset(x: -self.offset, y: 0)
```

Comment: You can use idea from [How to make a SwiftUI List scroll automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258846/how-to-make-a-swiftui-list-scroll-automatically/58708206#58708206) post

Comment: That's for that reference! That's definitely a possibility but wow it's a lot of code for such a simple operation.

Comment: I wonder if you have found a better solution to this since it's been a year? I'm having the exact issue now.

Comment: The solution is using Xcode 12 with iOS 14 and the latest SwiftUI 2.0 which I believe has the methods needed to set offset now.

Answer (score -1):

In apple's example swiftUI Code, they just use padding of cell in ScrollView. Maybe it is an answer from apple.