# How to scroll List programmatically in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

It looks like in current tools/system, just released Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4, there will be no SwiftUI-native support for "scroll-to" feature in `List`. So even if they, Apple, will provide it in next *major* released, I will need backward support for iOS 13.x.

So how would I do it in most simple & light way?

- scroll List to end
- scroll List to top
- and others

(I don't like wrapping full `UITableView` infrastructure into `UIViewRepresentable/UIViewControllerRepresentable` as was proposed earlier on SO).

Comment: The Form or List won't scroll it you make the height larger than the scrollable area using `.frame(height: x)`, where x is a value larger than the content height.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**SWIFTUI 2.0**

Here is possible alternate solution in Xcode 12 / iOS 14 (SwiftUI 2.0) that can be used in same scenario when controls for scrolling is outside of scrolling area (because SwiftUI2 `ScrollViewReader` can be used only *inside* `ScrollView`)

*Note: Row content design is out of consideration scope*

Tested with Xcode 12b / iOS 14

[image: demo2]

```
class ScrollToModel: ObservableObject {
    enum Action {
        case end
        case top
    }
    @Published var direction: Action? = nil
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ScrollToModel()

    let items = (0..<200).map { $0 }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: { vm.direction = .top }) { // < here
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.up.to.line")
                      .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                Button(action: { vm.direction = .end }) { // << here
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.down.to.line")
                      .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
            Divider()
            
            ScrollViewReader { sp in
                ScrollView {
               
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text("Item \(item)").id(item)
                                Divider()
                            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity).padding(.horizontal)
                        }
                    }.onReceive(vm.$direction) { action in
                        guard !items.isEmpty else { return }
                        withAnimation {
                            switch action {
                                case .top:
                                    sp.scrollTo(items.first!, anchor: .top)
                                case .end:
                                    sp.scrollTo(items.last!, anchor: .bottom)
                                default:
                                    return
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SWIFTUI 1.0+**

Here is simplified variant of approach that works, looks appropriate, and takes a couple of screens code.

Tested with Xcode 11.2+ / iOS 13.2+ (also with Xcode 12b / iOS 14)

**Demo of usage:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let scrollingProxy = ListScrollingProxy() // proxy helper

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: { self.scrollingProxy.scrollTo(.top) }) { // < here
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.up.to.line")
                      .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                Button(action: { self.scrollingProxy.scrollTo(.end) }) { // << here
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.down.to.line")
                      .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
            Divider()
            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< 200) { i in
                    Text("Item \(i)")
                        .background(
                           ListScrollingHelper(proxy: self.scrollingProxy) // injection
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

**Solution:**

Light view representable being injected into `List` gives access to UIKit's view hierarchy. As `List` reuses rows there are no more values then fit rows into screen.

```
struct ListScrollingHelper: UIViewRepresentable {
    let proxy: ListScrollingProxy // reference type

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return UIView() // managed by SwiftUI, no overloads
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        proxy.catchScrollView(for: uiView) // here UIView is in view hierarchy
    }
}
```

Simple proxy that finds enclosing `UIScrollView` (needed to do once) and then redirects needed "scroll-to" actions to that stored scrollview

```
class ListScrollingProxy {
    enum Action {
        case end
        case top
        case point(point: CGPoint)     // << bonus !!
    }

    private var scrollView: UIScrollView?

    func catchScrollView(for view: UIView) {
        if nil == scrollView {
            scrollView = view.enclosingScrollView()
        }
    }

    func scrollTo(_ action: Action) {
        if let scroller = scrollView {
            var rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
            switch action {
                case .end:
                    rect.origin.y = scroller.contentSize.height +
                        scroller.contentInset.bottom + scroller.contentInset.top - 1
                case .point(let point):
                    rect.origin.y = point.y
                default: {
                    // default goes to top
                }()
            }
            scroller.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func enclosingScrollView() -> UIScrollView? {
        var next: UIView? = self
        repeat {
            next = next?.superview
            if let scrollview = next as? UIScrollView {
                return scrollview
            }
        } while next != nil
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I have some issue with this solution. It appears to work only if you previously interacted with the list. Did you notice that or it's `11.4.1` thing?

Comment: @Błażej, I have not migrated to 11.4.1 yet, so probably it's update issue. With 11.4 all works fine.

Comment: I'm using this in a scrollview. It only works if after i interact a little with the scrollview. "if let scroller = scrollView {" doesn't conform immediately

Comment: i solved it by redeclaring self.scrollingProxy = ListScrollingProxy() after the ScrollView content was fully loaded

Comment: how to scroll to the very specific cell?  Let say I want to scroll to the  40th cell.

Comment: Thank you @Asperi ! I wanted to use a floating button to scroll a ScrollView to the top, but the button wasn't within ScrollViewReader, instead they were side by side in a ZStack. This exactly solved the problem.

Comment: @FilipeSá how to detect when ScrollView content was fully loaded? i have the same issue

Comment: @AmineArous in my case, I populate a List with JSON from the web, after I get and add the data to the list, I do: DispatchQueue.main.async { self.scrollingProxy = ListScrollingProxy() }

Comment: [Apple's SwiftUI 2 documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader) shows the `ScrollViewReader` declared as the parent of the `ScrollView`. Seems to work either way.

Comment: Another approach that I took to make it work at the initial loading is that: I added 'weak var sampleView: UIView?' to ListScrollingProxy and on 'catchScrollView' assigned it to 'sampleView = view'. Then in 'scrollToMethod' did the following: 'if scrollView == nil {
            if let sampleView = sampleView {
                scrollView = sampleView.enclosingScrollView()
            }
        }'. Here is my gist link https://gist.github.com/gsoykan/4b77614aa827ba3243e0ed9b7e268ad4

Answer (score 18):

## Just scroll to the id:

```
scrollView.scrollTo(ROW-ID)
```

---

Since SwiftUI structured designed Data-Driven, You should know all of your items IDs. So you can scroll to any id with `ScrollViewReader` from **iOS 14** and with **Xcode 12**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let items = (1...100)

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { Text("\($0)"); Divider() }
            }

            HStack {
                Button("First!") { withAnimation { scrollProxy.scrollTo(items.first!) } }
                Button("Any!") { withAnimation { scrollProxy.scrollTo(50) } }
                Button("Last!") { withAnimation { scrollProxy.scrollTo(items.last!) } }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note that** `ScrollViewReader` should support all scrollable content, but *now* it only supports `ScrollView`

---

## Preview

[image: preview]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the nice solution. I am trying to do similar things. However, I want to control the animation time. While moving Position 1st to 7th will take a total of 1 second. I tried this way withAnimation (.linear(duration: 1)){
                    reader.scrollTo(7)
                }. But there is no control over customize animation time. It's animating with default time. Do you have any idea on this.

Answer (score 14):

### Preferred way

This answer is getting more attention, but I should state that the `ScrollViewReader` is the right way to do this. The introspect way is only if the reader/proxy doesn't work for you, because of a version restrictions.

```
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
        TopView().id("TopConstant")
        ...
        MiddleView().id("MiddleConstant")
        ...
        Button("Go to top") {
            proxy.scrollTo("TopConstant", anchor: .top)
        }
        .id("BottomConstant")
    }
    .onAppear{
        proxy.scrollTo("MiddleConstant")
    }
    .onChange(of: viewModel.someProperty) { _ in
        proxy.scrollTo("BottomConstant")
    }
}
```

The strings should be defined in one place, outside of the body property.

### Legacy answer

Here is a simple solution that works on iOS13&14:
Using [Introspect](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Introspect).
My case was for initial scroll position.

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
        ...
    })
    .introspectScrollView(customize: { scrollView in
        scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: offset, width: 100, height: 300), animated: false)
    })
```

If needed the height may be calculated from the screen size or the element itself.
This solution is for Vertical scroll. For horizontal you should specify x and leave y as 0

Comment: this best answer to target SwiftUI 1.0

Comment: I needed to use .onChange to scroll to the top and this helped me nail it. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Thanks Asperi, great tip.  I needed to have a List scroll up when new entries where added outside the view.  Reworked to suit macOS.

I took the state/proxy variable to an environmental object and used this outside the view to force the scroll.  I found I had to update it twice, the 2nd time with a .5sec delay to get the best result.  The first update prevents the view from scrolling back to the top as the row is added.  The 2nd update scrolls to the last row.  I'm a novice and this is my first stackoverflow post :o

**Updated for MacOS:**

```
struct ListScrollingHelper: NSViewRepresentable {

    let proxy: ListScrollingProxy // reference type

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        return NSView() // managed by SwiftUI, no overloads
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
        proxy.catchScrollView(for: nsView) // here NSView is in view hierarchy
    }
}

class ListScrollingProxy {
    //updated for mac osx
    enum Action {
        case end
        case top
        case point(point: CGPoint)     // << bonus !!
    }

    private var scrollView: NSScrollView?

    func catchScrollView(for view: NSView) {
        //if nil == scrollView { //unB - seems to lose original view when list is emptied
            scrollView = view.enclosingScrollView()
        //}
    }

    func scrollTo(_ action: Action) {
        if let scroller = scrollView {
            var rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
            switch action {
                case .end:
                    rect.origin.y = scroller.contentView.frame.minY
                    if let documentHeight = scroller.documentView?.frame.height {
                        rect.origin.y = documentHeight - scroller.contentSize.height
                    }
                case .point(let point):
                    rect.origin.y = point.y
                default: {
                    // default goes to top
                }()
            }
            //tried animations without success :(
            scroller.contentView.scroll(to: NSPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
            scroller.reflectScrolledClipView(scroller.contentView)
        }
    }
}
extension NSView {
    func enclosingScrollView() -> NSScrollView? {
        var next: NSView? = self
        repeat {
            next = next?.superview
            if let scrollview = next as? NSScrollView {
                return scrollview
            }
        } while next != nil
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use this for animations:     
``` 
NSAnimationContext.beginGrouping()

      NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 6.0

      let clipView = scroller.contentView

      var newOrigin = clipView.bounds.origin

      newOrigin.x = rect.minX

      newOrigin.y = rect.minY

      clipView.animator().setBoundsOrigin(newOrigin)

      NSAnimationContext.endGrouping()
      ```

Answer (score 8):

my two cents for deleting and repositioning list at any point based on other logic.. i.e. after delete/update, for example going to top.
(this is a ultra-reduced sample, I used this code after network call back to reposition: after network call I change previousIndex )

struct ContentView: View {

```
@State private var previousIndex : Int? = nil
@State private var items = Array(0...100)

func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    self.previousIndex = offsets.first
}

var body: some View {
    ScrollViewReader { (proxy: ScrollViewProxy) in
        List{
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { Text("\($0)")
            }.onDelete(perform: removeRows)
        }.onChange(of: previousIndex) { (e: Equatable) in
            proxy.scrollTo(previousIndex!-4, anchor: .top)
            //proxy.scrollTo(0, anchor: .top) // will display 1st cell
        }

    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: I would just like to point out that this is the only solution, which uses List, as the title of the question is asked. Tested on iOS 15.1, and works. Thank you.

Comment: thx Tom! testing on iOS 16

Answer (score 3):

This can now be simplified with all new [`ScrollViewProxy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewproxy) in Xcode 12, like so:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let itemCount: Int = 100
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            VStack {
                Button("Scroll to top") {
                    value.scrollTo(0)
                }
                
                Button("Scroll to buttom") {
                    value.scrollTo(itemCount-1)
                }
                
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(0 ..< itemCount) { i in
                            Text("Item \(i)")
                                .frame(height: 50)
                                .id(i)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MacOS 11: In case you need to scroll a list based on input outside the view hierarchy.  I have followed the original scroll proxy pattern using the new scrollViewReader:

```
struct ScrollingHelperInjection: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    let proxy: ScrollViewProxy
    let helper: ScrollingHelper

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        return NSView()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
        helper.catchProxy(for: proxy)
    }
}

final class ScrollingHelper {
    //updated for mac os v11

    private var proxy: ScrollViewProxy?
    
    func catchProxy(for proxy: ScrollViewProxy) {
        self.proxy = proxy
    }

    func scrollTo(_ point: Int) {
        if let scroller = proxy {
            withAnimation() {
                scroller.scrollTo(point)
            }
        } else {
            //problem
        }
    }
}
```

Environmental object:
`@Published var scrollingHelper = ScrollingHelper()`

In the view: `ScrollViewReader { reader in .....`

Injection in the view:
`.background(ScrollingHelperInjection(proxy: reader, helper: scrollingHelper)`

Usage outside the view hierarchy: `scrollingHelper.scrollTo(3)`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in @lachezar-todorov's answer [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) is a nice library to access `UIKit` elements in `SwiftUI`. But be aware that the block you use for accessing `UIKit` elements are being called multiple times. This can really mess up your app state. In my cas CPU usage was going %100 and app was getting unresponsive. I had to use some pre conditions to avoid it.

```
ScrollView() {
    ...
}.introspectScrollView { scrollView in
    if aPreCondition {
        //Your scrolling logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another cool way is to just use namespace wrappers:

> A dynamic property type that allows access to a namespace defined by the persistent identity of the object containing the property (e.g. a view).

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Namespace private var topID
    @Namespace private var bottomID
    
    let items = (0..<100).map { $0 }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                
                Section {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            Text("Item \(items[index])")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.green.cornerRadius(16))
                        }
                    }
                } header: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("header")
                        
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                proxy.scrollTo(bottomID)
                                
                            }
                        }
                        ) {
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.down.to.line")
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .id(topID)
                    
                } footer: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Footer")
                        
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                proxy.scrollTo(topID) }
                        }
                        ) {
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.up.to.line")
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .id(bottomID)
                    
                }
                .padding()
                
                
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(.black)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

after reading some comment about using buttons outside the hierarchy, a rewrote a bit using scrollview, this time, hoping can help:

```swift
import SwiftUI
    
struct ContentView: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue]

    @State private var idx : Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Button("Jump to #12") {
                idx = 12
            }
            Button("Jump to #1") {
                idx = 1
            }
            
            ScrollViewReader { (proxy: ScrollViewProxy) in
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        
                        ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                            Text("Example \(i)")
                                .font(.title)
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                                .background(colors[i % colors.count])
                                .id(i)
                        }
                    } // HStack
                    
                }// ScrollView
                .frame(height: 350)
                .onChange(of: idx) { newValue in
                    withAnimation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(idx, anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                }

            } // ScrollViewReader
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two parts:

1. Wrap the `List` (or `ScrollView`) with `ScrollViewReader`
2. Use the `scrollViewProxy` (that comes from `ScrollViewReader`) to scroll to an `id` of an element in the `List`. You can seemingly use `EmptyView()`.

The example below uses a notification for simplicity (use a function if you can instead!).

```
ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
  List {
    EmptyView().id("top")  
  }
  .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .ScrollToTop)) { _ in
    // when using an anchor of `.top`, it failed to go all the way to the top
    // so here we add an extra -50 so it goes to the top
    scrollViewProxy.scrollTo("top", anchor: UnitPoint(x: 0, y: -50))
  }
}

extension Notification.Name {
  static let ScrollToTop = Notification.Name("ScrollToTop")
}

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .ScrollToTop, object: nil)
```