# Scrollview conflicting with another scrollview. Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, conditional-operator

I have a scrollview who's content expands to fill the screen and stacks in front using the zIndex. The expanded content also has a scrollview for the content inside. I'm literally trying to mimic the Apps Stores "Today" tab with expanding cards and scrollable content inside.
The way I built this though I realized the expanding view is still part of the parent scrollview. As a result the scrollviews are nested and conflict. This was not what I intended.

Im very new to programming. This is the code that basically expands each card. Its pretty basic. A ternary expands the cards. The CardView is the cards content. Attached is a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve. Need help here. Any info would be great. Been searching the internet for a way to do this right.

```
        struct Media: View {

@EnvironmentObject var vm : ViewModel
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var mode
@State var showCard = false
@State var activeCard = -1
let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        
        ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            
            VStack (alignment:.center, spacing: 30) {
                
                ForEach (vm.cards.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                    
                    let z=vm.cards[i].z
                    
                    GeometryReader { geom in
                        
                        ZStack {
                            
                            CardView (showCard: $showCard,
                                      activeCard: self.$activeCard,
                                      zValue: $vm.cards[i].z,
                                      i: i,
                                      cards: vm.cards[i])
                            
                        }//Z
                        .frame(minHeight: showCard && activeCard == i ? height : nil) //Animates Card Scaling
                        .padding(.horizontal, showCard && activeCard == i ? 0:20) // Card Padding
                        .offset(y: i==activeCard ? -geom.frame(in: .global).minY : 0)
                        
                    } //GEOM
                    .frame(minHeight: 450)
                    .zIndex(z)
                    
                } //LOOP
                
            } //V
            .padding([.bottom, .top])

        } //SCROLLVIEW
        

    } //Z
    .background(Color("Background Gray"))
    
}
```

}
[image]

Comment: the easiest way would be to show the detail view with the copy text in a `.sheet` or `.fullScreenCover`... would that be acceptable?

Comment: Thanks. For this app I'm making I want it to function this specific way, with a smooth transition from card to fullscreen then back to card. Don't those slide up from the bottom only??

Comment: yes, those would slide up ... but I tried something. see below

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with the nested `ScrollView`s, as you put the DetailView on top. I tried to rebuild a simplified version from your code, see below.

BTW: You don't need the outer `ZStack`.
And at some point you should consider using `ForEach` over the `cards`, not over the `indices`, otherwise you'll run into UI update problems when inserting or deleting cards. I left it for now to stay closer to your original.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var activeCard = -1
    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            
            VStack (alignment:.center, spacing: 30) {
                
                ForEach (data.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                    
                    GeometryReader { geom in
                        
                        ZStack {
                            
                            DetailCellView(entry: data[i], isActive: activeCard == i)
                            
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    if activeCard == i {
                                        activeCard = -1
                                    } else {
                                        activeCard = i
                                    }
                                }
                            
                        }//Z
                        .frame(minHeight: activeCard == i ? height : nil) //Animates Card Scaling
                        .padding(.horizontal, activeCard == i ? 0 : 20) // Card Padding
                        .offset(y: activeCard == i ? -geom.frame(in: .global).minY : 0)
                        
                    } //GEOM
                    .frame(minHeight: 450)
                    .zIndex(activeCard == i ? 1 : 0)
                    
                    .animation(.default, value: activeCard)
                    
                } //LOOP
                
            } //V
//            .padding([.bottom, .top])
            
        } //SCROLLVIEW
        
        .background(.gray)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem I seem to have is when the scrollview comes completely to rest at the top or bottom and then I try to drag more for the bounce effect, I end up dragging the main scrollview instead. Not sure if that happens with you??

Comment: yes, I didn't realize, but I have the same problem. I can disable the inner (DetailView) ScrollView when not active by adding `.disabled(!isActive)`, but that won't work with the outer, because the outer overwrites the inner – so then nothing is scrollable anymore. I will keep trying ...

Comment: I tried so many solution but none seem to either work, or maintain a seamless experience. I feel like when the card expands it needs to escape the scrollview to the top level, if such am thing is possible.

Comment: Actually this seems to be a bug. It makes no sene that you can scroll in one direction, but not in the other. You should file a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Dang. I was hoping I was just doing something wrong. Ok.

Answer (score 0):

for the while being: a custom outer dragview as workaround ...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var activeCard = -1
    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    
    @State private var offset = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var drag = CGFloat.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack (alignment:.center, spacing: 30) {
                
                ForEach (data.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                    
                    GeometryReader { geom in
                        
                        ZStack {
                            DetailCellView(entry: data[i],
                                           isActive: activeCard == i)
                            
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    if activeCard == i {
                                        activeCard = -1
                                    } else {
                                        activeCard = i
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                        .frame(minHeight: activeCard == i ? height : nil) //Animates Card Scaling
                        .padding(.horizontal, activeCard == i ? 0 : 20) // Card Padding
                        .offset(y: activeCard == i ? -geom.frame(in: .global).minY : 0)
                        
                    }
                    .frame(minHeight: 400)
                    .zIndex(activeCard == i ? 1 : 0)
                    
                    .animation(.default, value: activeCard)
                    
                }
            }
            
            // custom drag view
            .offset(x: 0 , y: offset + drag)
            .background(.gray)
            
            // drag
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                drag = value.translation.height
            })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                print(offset)
                
                withAnimation(.easeOut)  {
                    offset += value.predictedEndTranslation.height
                    offset = min(offset, 0)
                    offset = max(offset, -CGFloat(data.count * (400 + 30)) + height )
                    drag = 0
                }
                print(offset)
            })
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to accomplish what I was trying to accomplish.

```
struct ScrollingHelper: UIViewRepresentable {

let proxy: ScrollingProxy // reference type

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    
    return UIView() // managed by SwiftUI, no overloads
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    
    proxy.catchScrollView(for: uiView) // here UIView is in view hierarchy
}
}


class ScrollingProxy {
private var scrollView: UIScrollView?
func catchScrollView(for view: UIView) {
    
    if nil == scrollView {
        
        scrollView = view.enclosingScrollView()
    }
}

func disableScrolling(_ flag: Bool) {
    scrollView?.isScrollEnabled = flag
    print(flag)
    
}

}

extension UIView {
func enclosingScrollView() -> UIScrollView? {
    var next: UIView? = self
    repeat {
        next = next?.superview
        if let scrollview = next as? UIScrollView {
            return scrollview
        }
    } while next != nil
    return nil
}
}
```

I used the above code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855853/12299030 &
[Disable Scrolling in SwiftUI List/Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60905671/disable-scrolling-in-swiftui-list-form/60910593#60910593)

Then used in a TapGesture

```
scrollEnabled = false

scrollProxy.disableScrolling(scrollEnabled)
```

and used background modifier:

```
.background(ScrollingHelper(proxy: scrollProxy))
```