# SwiftUI zIndex inside List

Tags: swift, swiftui

The `zIndex` property on a view inside a `ForEach` inside `List` does not seem to work whereas if you have `zIndex` inside a ForEach inside a `ScrollView`, it does.

Does not work for me:

```
List {
    ForEach { index
       View()
          .zIndex(index == 1 ? 1 : 0)
    }
}
```

Works:

```
VStack {
    ScrollView {
        ForEach { index
           View()
              .zIndex(index == 1 ? 1 : 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: What is the `View` type you are using?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `Does not work`? Does it not compile? crash? or just not have the expected behavior?

Comment: @Sam Sorry, to be clear the zIndex does not take effect, the "row" I'm forcing to the top zIndex does not actually go to the top. `View` is some custom view I have created

Comment: My guess would be a bug in SwiftUI — maybe try sticking `Group`s everywhere and see if it has an effect?

Comment: No luck with the `Group`s :(

Comment: It is not clear what you try to do, because List layouts row views by Y coordinate (w/o overlap), however zIndex affects Z coordinate. Would you provide more real example?

Answer (score 1):

It seems zIndex is not working inside *List* in *SwiftUI* (even SwiftUI 2). One workaround could be to introspect the *UITableViewCell* and change its ***zPosition*** of the layer, Like the following;

```
 var body: some View {
    List {
        Text("First Row")
            .background(Color.green)
            .padding()
            .listRowZIndex(1)
        Text("Second Row")
            .background(Color.red)
            .padding()
            .listRowZIndex(0)
            .offset(x: 0, y: -30)
    }
 }
```

Then create the ViewModifier ;

```
struct ListRowZIndex: ViewModifier {
    
    @State var zIndex : CGFloat = 0.0
        
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.background(ListRowZindexHelperView(zIndex: zIndex))
    }
}

extension View {
    func listRowZIndex(_ index: CGFloat = 0.0) -> some View {
            self.modifier(ListRowZIndex(zIndex: index))
    }
}
```

Required implementation;

```
struct ListRowZindexHelperView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let zIndex : CGFloat
    let proxy = ListRowZindexHelperProxy(cellWrapper: UITableViewCellWrapper(cell: UITableViewCell()))
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return UIView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        proxy.catchUITableViewCell(for: uiView)
        proxy.chnageZIndex(zIndex)
    }
}


class ListRowZindexHelperProxy {

    var uiTableViewCellWrapper: UITableViewCellWrapper
    
    init(cellWrapper: UITableViewCellWrapper) {
        uiTableViewCellWrapper = cellWrapper
    }

    func catchUITableViewCell(for view: UIView) {
        if let cell = view.enclosingUITableViewCell() {
            uiTableViewCellWrapper.uiTableViewCell = cell
        }
    }

    func chnageZIndex(_ zIndex: CGFloat = 0.0) {
        uiTableViewCellWrapper.uiTableViewCell.layer.zPosition = zIndex
    }
}

class UITableViewCellWrapper {
    var uiTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    
    init(cell: UITableViewCell) {
        uiTableViewCell = cell
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func enclosingUITableViewCell() -> UITableViewCell? {
        var next: UIView? = self
        repeat {
            next = next?.superview
            if let asUITableViewCell = next as? UITableViewCell {
                return asUITableViewCell
            }
        } while next != nil
        return nil
    }
}
```

Result;
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H99LC.png)

The Second row goes behind the first row since first row has a higher zIndex now

Answer is inspired [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855852/how-to-scroll-list-programmatically-in-swiftui)

Comment: Ah, the "elegance" of SwiftUI! The above is not working for me in Xcode 13.4.1, failing to walk up the view hierarchy saying that the superview of the added background view is nil