# SwiftUI tvOS button animation - how to stop y axis movement

Tags: animation, button, swiftui, marquee

this simple code of x offset animation causes a text to move also on y axis when the text is part of a button (on tvOS 14.7)

```
struct Animate: View
{
    @State var scrollText: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Text("This is My Text !")
                .offset(x: scrollText ? 0 : 200, y: 0)
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true))
                .onAppear {
                  self.scrollText.toggle()
                }
        })
    }
}
```

see the animation behavior here:
[marquee gone wrong](https://streamable.com/9plrvd)

How can i stop the y axis movement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to set a `value` for your animations. Otherwise, SwiftUI will animate all changes, include unwanted positioning.

```
struct Animate: View {
    @State var scrollText: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("This is My Text !")
                .offset(x: scrollText ? 0 : 200, y: 0)
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: scrollText) /// only update animation when `scrollText` changes
                .onAppear {
//                    DispatchQueue.main.async { /// you might also need this
                        self.scrollText.toggle()
//                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: No weird position animation]

[*This video might also be helpful*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sDFCAh_yT8&t=222s)

Comment: I couldn't see any difference from my original code,  regarding unset values, but after i un-remarked: "DispatchQueue.main.async" lines - it worked, perfect!, thanks allot