# Scroll info from SwiftUI List - UIViewRepresentable UIScrollView List bindings not always working with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, swiftui

I'm trying to observe/get some of SwiftUI's List scrolling attributes by wrapping/injection of UIScrollView using UIViewRepresentable.

I'm getting inconsistent behavior with bindings.

Pressing the buttons and changing values depending on if the button is in the parent vs child view has different results.

The bindings from my ObservableObject ScrollInfo class and the UIViewRepresentable start fine, but then break, unless the whole screen is refreshed and makeUIView runs again (like changing to a different tab).

Is there a way to force the UIViewRepresentable to run makeUIView again on a binding update? Or something that will fix this?

I'd like for isScrolling values to be updated and working all the time.

I set up a test to change the colors of the circles to red if the user is dragging the scrollview down. It works initially but stops if I update a value from the ObservableObject in the parent view.

**Screenshots of Test from code below**

[Bindings keep working with bottom button press (updating ObservableObject) in child view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV0L9.jpg)

[Bindings break with top button press (updating ObservableObject) in parent view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVh8Q.jpg)

```
// Parent View

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var scrollInfo:ScrollInfo = ScrollInfo()
    var body: some View {
  VStack
               {
                   Button(action:{
                    self.scrollInfo.contentLoaded = true;
                       
                   })
                   {
                       Text("REFRESH")
                   }
             TestView()
             
           }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

// Child View


import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {

     @State var test1:String = "Test1"
    @ObservedObject var scrollInfo:ScrollInfo = ScrollInfo()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack
            {
                Button(action:{
                    self.scrollInfo.contentLoaded.toggle()
                               })  {
                                             Text("REFRESH")
                                         }
        
        List{
            VStack  {

               
                VStack{
                    Text(String( self.scrollInfo.contentLoaded))
                         Text(self.test1)
                         Circle().frame(width:50,height:50).foregroundColor(self.scrollInfo.isScrolling ? .red : .green)
                }
                VStack{
                         Text(self.scrollInfo.text)
                         Text(self.test1)
                         Circle().frame(width:50,height:50).foregroundColor(self.scrollInfo.isScrolling ? .red : .green)
                }
                
                
                         VStack{
                                  Text(self.scrollInfo.text)
                                  Text(self.test1)
                                  Circle().frame(width:50,height:50).foregroundColor(self.scrollInfo.isScrolling ? .red : .green)
                         }
                         
                
                         VStack{
                                  Text(self.scrollInfo.text)
                                  Text(self.test1)
                                  Circle().frame(width:50,height:50).foregroundColor(self.scrollInfo.isScrolling ? .red : .green)
                         }
                         
                
            }   .padding(.bottom,620).padding(.top,20)
          .background(
            ListScrollingHelper(scrollInfo: self.scrollInfo)// injection
            )
        }.padding(.top,4).onAppear(perform:{
            
        })
        }
        
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}


// ScrollInfo Class



class ScrollInfo: ObservableObject {

    @Published var isScrolling:Bool = false
    @Published var text:String = "Blank"
    @Published var contentLoaded:Bool = false

    init()
    {
        print( "scrollInfo init")
    }
    deinit {
        print("scrollInfo denit")
    }

}

// UIViewRepresentable


final class ListScrollingHelper: UIViewRepresentable {
    var scrollInfo:ScrollInfo
    @Published var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    
    init( scrollInfo:ScrollInfo) {
        print("init UIViewRepresentable listscrolling helper")
        self.scrollInfo = scrollInfo
        
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        
        //self.uiScrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
        print("makeview")
        return UIView()
        //return self.uiScrollView // managed by SwiftUI, no overloads
    }
    func catchScrollView(for view: UIView) {
        print("checking for scrollview")
        if nil == scrollView {
            scrollView = view.enclosingScrollView()
            if(scrollView != nil)
            {
                print("scrollview found")
            }
        }
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        
       
      catchScrollView(for: uiView)
        if(scrollView != nil)
                {
          scrollView!.delegate = context.coordinator
    }
        
        print("updatingUIView")
        
    }
   
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
              
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject,UIScrollViewDelegate {
        
        var parent: ListScrollingHelper

        init(_ listScrollingHelper: ListScrollingHelper) {
            self.parent = listScrollingHelper
            print("init coordinator")
        }

        func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
                  // DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       if(!self.parent.scrollInfo.isScrolling)
                       {
                   self.parent.scrollInfo.isScrolling = true
                   //self.parent.scrollInfo.text = "scroll"
                       //       }
                   }
                   print("start scroll")
            
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        
            if(self.parent.scrollInfo.isScrolling && !decelerate)
                                 {
                  self.parent.scrollInfo.isScrolling = false
                  }
                   print("end scroll")
                  
                     }
        func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            if(self.parent.scrollInfo.isScrolling)
                           {
            self.parent.scrollInfo.isScrolling = false
            }
             print("end scroll")
            
               }
        
           deinit
           {
               print("deinit coordinator")
           }
     

    }
    
    deinit {
          print("deinit UIViewRepresentable listscrolling helper")
    }
}
extension UIView {
    func enclosingScrollView() -> UIScrollView? {
        var next: UIView? = self
        repeat {
            next = next?.superview
            if let scrollview = next as? UIScrollView {
                return scrollview
            }
        } while next != nil
        return nil
    }
}
```

**EDIT - WORKAROUND**

I wasn't able to get it working with the ObservableObject or EnvironmentObject, but I was able to get it working with @State and @Binding, although it's a limited amount of info passed back. (ScrollInfo is still there only to use to testing changing a parent ObservableObject)

Hope this helps someone else!

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {

    @State var isScrolling:Bool = false;
    var body: some View {
        VStack
            {
                Button(action:{
                    self.scrollInfo.contentLoaded.toggle()
                               })  {
                                             Text("REFRESH")
                                         }
        
        List{
            VStack  {

               
                VStack{
                    Text("isScrolling")
                    Text(String(self.isScrolling))
                         Circle().frame(width:50,height:50).foregroundColor(self.isScrolling ? .red : .green)
                }
                VStack{
                         Text(self.scrollInfo.text)
                         Text(self.test1)
                         Circle().frame(width:50,height:50).foregroundColor(self.isScrolling ? .red : .green)
                }
                
                
                         VStack{
                                  Text(self.scrollInfo.text)
                                  Text(self.test1)
                                  Circle().frame(width:50,height:50).foregroundColor(self.isScrolling ? .red : .green)
                         }
                         
                
                         VStack{
                                  Text(self.scrollInfo.text)
                                  Text(self.test1)
                                  Circle().frame(width:50,height:50).foregroundColor(self.isScrolling ? .red : .green)
                         }
                         
                
                }   .padding(.bottom,620).padding(.top,20).background( ListScrollingHelper(isScrolling: self.$isScrolling))
            
        }.padding(.top,4)
        
    }
}
}

extension UIView {
    func enclosingScrollView() -> UIScrollView? {
        var next: UIView? = self
        repeat {
            next = next?.superview
            if let scrollview = next as? UIScrollView {
                return scrollview
            }
        } while next != nil
        return nil
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}


final class ListScrollingHelper: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var isScrolling:Bool
    private var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    
    init(isScrolling:Binding<Bool>)
    {
        self._isScrolling = isScrolling
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return UIView()
    }
    func catchScrollView(for view: UIView) {
        if nil == scrollView {
            scrollView = view.enclosingScrollView()
        }
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        
       
      catchScrollView(for: uiView)
        if(scrollView != nil)
                {
          scrollView!.delegate = context.coordinator
    }
        
    }
   
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
              
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject,UIScrollViewDelegate {
        
        var parent: ListScrollingHelper

        init(_ listScrollingHelper: ListScrollingHelper) {
            self.parent = listScrollingHelper
        }

        func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
                       if(!self.parent.isScrolling)
                       {
                   self.parent.isScrolling = true
                   }
            
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        
            if(self.parent.isScrolling && !decelerate)
                                 {
                  self.parent.isScrolling = false
                  }
                  
                     }
        func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            if(self.parent.isScrolling)
                           {
            self.parent.isScrolling = false
            }
               }
        
           deinit
           {
           }
     

    }
    
    deinit {
    }
}



class ScrollInfo: ObservableObject {

    @Published var isScrolling:Bool = false
    @Published var text:String = "Blank"
    @Published var contentLoaded:Bool = false

}
```

Comment: The solution in [How to scroll List programmatically in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855852/how-to-scroll-list-programmatically-in-swiftui) should be helpful.

Comment: Yes, that's actually where I started and built from there. I wasn't able to use my code in the end, because with the actual app with Lists and scrollviews everywhere, it would stop working, and it was consuming too much memory each time. Seems like some things in SwiftUI are optimized and when adding UIKit, things don't perform as well.