# Keep user at the current scroll position when elements in ForEach loop update swiftui

Tags: swift, foreach, uiscrollview, swiftui, scrollview

I'm working on a project in SwiftUI and have a forEach loop, something like this:

```
ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
    Text(item)
        .padding(4)
}
```

and when I update `self.items` the ForEach view updates, but it also forces the scroll position back to the very top. Is there a way I could get the ForEach view to update and add the items without changing the current scroll position the user was at?

Any help with this matter would be appreciated. Also, I would prefer a non-iOS 14 method, since I'm working on an application to be released soon and don't expect it to be compatible with iOS 14.

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Look at solution in [How to scroll List programmatically in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855853/12299030), section for SwiftUI 1.0+.

Comment: Did you figure out the cause and a solution?