# Block scroll down in ScrollView - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

How can I block scroll down and only allow scroll up in order to avoid seeing the white space over the rectangle on top when scrolling?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView {
                Rectangle()
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 400)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are concerned about the white space you can add a background for your scroll view using ZStack.

Comment: even if it was dark or with an image I just don't want the view to scroll down

Answer (score 9):

### Update: re-tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

I assume you want to avoid bounces, here is possible approach (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView {
                Rectangle()
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 1800)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .background(ScrollViewConfigurator {
                    $0?.bounces = false               // << here !!
                })
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollViewConfigurator: UIViewRepresentable {
    let configure: (UIScrollView?) -> ()
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            configure(view.enclosingScrollView())
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

*Note: `enclosingScrollView()` helper is taken from my answer in [How to scroll List programmatically in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855853/12299030)*

[Test module in project is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestScrollViewBouncing.swift)

Comment: I will try it soon. I just don't understand what should I put instead of enclosingScrollView

Comment: @asperi it is not working in Xcode 14

Comment: Yes, @venky is right. `enclosingScrollView` is missing. I don't see that a simple property modifier put into SwiftUI, do you?