# Disable ScrollView bounces of a single view - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, uitableview, swiftui, scrollview, uiappearance

How can I disable ScrollView bounces of a single view without affecting the others?

```
UITableView.appearance().bounces = false
```

If I initialize this code it disable bounces of all ScrollView istance. Is there any way to switch between false and true when changing a view or directly modifying that particular ScrollView?

Comment: Consider this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/63322713/12299030

Comment: I tried to do that in two different views changing false value to true and that works but if I have a navigationBarTitle in default mode and scroll up it changes into inline mode and never goes back to default mode