# How to layout properly in ZStack (I have visibility problem)?

Tags: swiftui, z-index, zstack

Here is reproducable small code below;

As you'll see when you run the demo code, the `Element` view does stay under `Color.blue` when dragged eventhough its above according to `ZStack`. By the way I also played with `zIndex` modifier but still no luck. Any solution you offer? Thanks all.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gr in
            
            ZStack {
            
                Color.blue.opacity(0.3)
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: gr.size.width)
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(1...15, id: \.self) { (idx) in
                                Element(index: idx)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    .background(Color.secondary.opacity(0.3))
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct Element: View {
    
    @State private var dragAmount = CGSize.zero
    
    var index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
            .overlay(Text("\(index)").bold().foregroundColor(.white))
            .offset(dragAmount)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
                    .onChanged {
                        self.dragAmount = CGSize(width: $0.translation.width, height: $0.translation.height)
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        self.dragAmount = .zero
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: ZStack does not matter here, you drag Element *inside* ScrollView container.

Comment: How can achieve my goal then, like dragging `Element` on different view (in this scenario  `Color.blue`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### iOS 15.5: still valid

> How can achieve my goal then, like dragging Element on different view (in this scenario Color.blue)

Actually we need to disable clipping by `ScrollView`.

Below is possible approach based on helper extensions from my other answers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63322713/12299030 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855853/12299030)

[image: demo]

```
VStack {
    Spacer()
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack {
            ForEach(1...15, id: \.self) { (idx) in
                Element(index: idx)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(ScrollViewConfigurator {
          $0?.clipsToBounds = false              // << here !!
        })

        
    }
    .background(Color.secondary.opacity(0.3))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time & effort. @Asperi