# Can we disable the Top Bouncing of ScrollVIew in swift UI

Tags: swiftui

In swift this is easy to do, but in SwiftUI didn't found any solution

```
init() {
  UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
}
```

But it will change the global bouncing preferences, my requirement is to disable the top bouncing in only specific view.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63322713/12299030?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799474/how-to-disable-scrollview-bounce-in-swiftui

Comment: @HuangRunhua this one will block entire bouncing into the app even in any direction, I'm looking for specific View and specific direction only