# SwiftUI Auto scroll - WITHOUT ScrollViewReader

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, ios13, autoscroll

I have a regular horizontal SwiftUI ScrollView, when the user clicks on a element, I want to ScrollView the focus on it (auto scroll to it so it becomes fully visible most left side on the ScrollView. Keep in mind, I can't use ScrollViewReader (iOS 13 support)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58708206/12299030? Or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855853/12299030 (see Swift 1.0 section)?

Comment: No, that is for List, I need to horizontal scroll view