# SwiftUI - ScrollView move selected item

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

Is it possible to move the selected item from horizontal ScrollView to the most far left position in the ScrollView? I can't use "scrollTo" which ScrollViewReader provides (iOS 13 support)
Bassicly I need to auto move the selected item so it becomes fully visible on the screen.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Consider this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855853/12299030 (section for SwiftUI 1.0)

Comment: Sadly, I need solution for a ScrollView not a List

Comment: It does not matter, both have UIScrollView inside.

Comment: when I tap the item from the scroll view and the scrollTo function start executing scrollView is nil, for some reason I can't figure out