# Scroll to selected position in scrollview when view loads - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

**OUTLINE**

I have 2 views, the first (view1) contains a `HStack` and an `@ObservableObject`. When the user selects a row from the `HStack` the `@ObservableObject` is updated to the string name of the row selected.

In view2 I have the same `HStack` as the first `HStack` in view1. This `HStack` observes `@ObservableObject` and desaturates all other rows except the one that matches the `@ObservableObject`.

**PROBLEM**

The `HStack` list in view2 is wider than the page so I would like to automatically scroll to the saturated/selected row when the view appears. I'm not totally sure how to use `ScrollTo` as it needs an integer and I am only storing/observing the string name.

**VIEW 1**

```
class selectedApplication: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedApplication = "application1"
}

struct view1: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var selectedOption = selectedApplication()

    var applications = ["application1", "application2", "application3", "application4", "application5", "application6", "application7", "application8", "application9", "application10"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                HStack{
                    ForEach(applications, id: \.self) { item in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.selectedOption.selectedApplication = item
                        }) {
                            VStack(alignment: .center){
                                Text(item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View2:**

```
struct View2: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var application: selectedApplication
    
    var applications = ["application1", "application2", "application3", "application4", "application5", "application6", "application7", "application8", "application9", "application10"]
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                ScrollViewReader{ scroll in
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(applications, id: \.self) { item in
                            Button(action: {
                                application.selectedApplication = item
                            }) {
                                Text(item)
                                    .saturation(application.selectedApplication == item ? 1.0 : 0.05)
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855853/12299030?

Comment: Roughly, thanks! I did look at `ScrollViewReader` and thought I would only need to store the row number and then use `scrollTo`. However, I don't know how to get the row int number selected so I can use `scrollTo` when the view is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ScrollViewReader` with the `id` that's being applied in the `ForEach`, so you don't actually need the row index number (although that, too, is possible to get, if you needed to, either by using `enumerated` or searching the `applications` array for the index of the item.

Here's my updated code:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject var selectedOption = SelectedApplicationState()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            View1(application: selectedOption)
            View2(application: selectedOption)
        }
    }
}

class SelectedApplicationState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedApplication = "application1"
    
    var applications = ["application1", "application2", "application3", "application4", "application5", "application6", "application7", "application8", "application9", "application10"]
}

struct View1: View {
    @ObservedObject var application: SelectedApplicationState

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                HStack{
                    ForEach(application.applications, id: \.self) { item in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.application.selectedApplication = item
                        }) {
                            VStack(alignment: .center){
                                Text(item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var application: SelectedApplicationState
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                ScrollViewReader{ scroll in
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(application.applications, id: \.self) { item in
                            Button(action: {
                                application.selectedApplication = item
                            }) {
                                Text(item)
                                    .saturation(application.selectedApplication == item ? 1.0 : 0.05)
                            }
                        }
                    }.onReceive(application.$selectedApplication) { (app) in
                        withAnimation {
                            scroll.scrollTo(app, anchor: .leading)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How it works:

1. I just made a basic ContentView to show the two views, since I wasn't sure how they're laid out for you
2. ContentView owns the `SelectedApplicationState` (which was your `selectionApplication` ObservableObject (by the way, it is common practice to capitalize your type names -- that's why I changed the name. Plus, it was confusing to have a type and a property of that type with such a similar name) and passes it to both views.
3. `SelectedApplicationState`  now holds the `applications` array, since it was being duplicated across views anyway
4. On selection in View1, `selectedApplication` in the ObservableObject is set, triggering `onReceive` in `View2`
5. There, the `ScrollViewReader` is told to scroll to the item with the id stored in `selectedApplication`, which is passed to the `onReceive` closure as `app`

In the event that these views are on separate pages, the position of View2 will *still* get set correctly once it is navigated to, because `onReceive` will fire on first load and set it to the correct position. The only requirement is passing that instance of `SelectedApplicationState` around.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.