# Programmatically Scroll SwiftUI ScrollView on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

I understand for iOS 14 you can use ScrollViewReader to automatically scroll your view up or down as the content in the scrollview changes.

I'm in a situation where I have to support iOS 13. Is there a way, even a hacky way, to programmatically scroll the scrollview in iOS 13?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855853/12299030?

Answer (score 1):

To do this on iOS 13 requires you to create a SwiftUI wrapper for a UIScrollView, and use the UIKit methods to achieve this.

Luckily there are several open source packages that can make this much easier for you. One of them is https://github.com/Amzd/ScrollViewProxy. I've used this package with good results in the past.

Example:

```swift
ScrollView { proxy in
  VStack {
    Text("A").scrollId("A")
    Text("B").scrollId("B")
    Text("C").scrollId("C")

    Button("Scroll to C") {
      proxy.scrollTo("C", alignment: .center)
    }

    Button("Scroll down") {
      proxy.scrollTo(.bottom)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get the ScrollViewProxy library to work...