# Is there a way to get the height of the ScrollView that contains the content in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to calculate how much I can scroll from the height of the entire ScrollView to the bottom of the ScrollView, but I can't get the height of the entire ScrollView.
If there is any way to do this, please let me know.

scrollView.contentSize.height
scrollView.frame.height

The top two are the values you want to get

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { number in
            Text("\(number)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The height of ScrollView itself or the height of a ScrollView's content?

Comment: scrollView.contentSize.height
scrollView.frame.height

The top two are the values you want to get

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on `ViewHeightKey` preference key from my answer in [How to make a SwiftUI List scroll automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58708206/12299030)

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { number in
                Text("\(number)")
            }
        }
        .modifier(ViewHeightKey())   // calculate here !!
    }
    .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { // read here !!
        print("Content height: \($0)")
    }
    .background(GeometryReader { gp -> Color in
        let frame = gp.frame(in: .local)
        print("ScrollView height: \(frame.size.height)")
        return Color.clear
    })
}
```

Comment: I got an error on geometryRender of backgroundmodifier.

Comment: error
Explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue

Comment: One more thing, I'm getting an error in the reduce of ViewHeightKey

error
Reference to invalid associated type 'Value' of type 'ViewHeightKey'

Comment: @zlatan, provided code snapshot tested & works with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4. I suppose  the origin of error in your adapting code.

Comment: Is there a way to get the contentOffset.y?