# the Chat styled ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to render several items using the chat style. This is a style where the elements are snapped to the bottom part of the window.
What is the most efficient way?
It's easy to scroll at a lot of items to the bottom. But what if I have only 1 or 2 elements? What if I want to implement an auto-scroll feature while appending a new item?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58708206/12299030?

Comment: looks good @Asperi thanks