# Specific arbitrary location of movable views in a ScrollView in SwiftUI (no auto-layout)

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, ipados

I would like to have a scroll view with a lot of subviews that have a custom location and can be touch-moved around by the user. They might also have some other controls in them (including text fields or even text editors). I tried the following:

```swift
struct CardThing: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let position: CGPoint
    let label: String
}

let cards: [CardThing] = [
    CardThing(id: 1, position: CGPoint(x: 00, y: 10), label: "Card one"),
    CardThing(id: 2, position: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20), label: "Card two"),
    CardThing(id: 3, position: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40), label: "Card three"),
    CardThing(id: 4, position: CGPoint(x: 60, y: 60), label: "Card four"),
]

// The following view is a view of a graph structure.
//
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // The scroll view should be either virtually infinite
        // or some auto-resizable based on content with reasonable
        // margins. When margins are reached it is resized to maintain
        // those margins. But that is not relevant to this question.
        ScrollView {
            // The content will usually be in couple of dozens or couple of hundreds
            ForEach(cards) {
                // Here it will be some kind of a card view in the future
                Text($0.label)
                    // The position is explicit, should not undergo auto-layout
                    .position($0.position)
                    // Frames might also differ, should not undergo some auto-sizing
                    .frame(width: 320, height: 200)
                    .border(Color.green)
            }

            // The following will also be part of the view, but it is assumed
            // that the answer to the original question will answer it. It is just
            // here to provide more context about the idea of the view's content.

            // ForEach(links) { ... display link as touchable line-like shape ... }
        }
        .frame(width:600, height: 400)
    }
}
```

But the preview result looked automatically (mis-)aligned (also note the incomplete labels):

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is not how standard ScrollView works - it does not have own size and tight to content. You will need custom scrollable area. This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/58708206/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi thanks for pointing that out. Although the auto-sizing is secondary. In the example above the size of the scroll view is fixed. My primary concern is arbitrary placement of the elements. As you can see in the screenshot - they are somehow aligned automatically not following the predefined explicit location.