# How to create own ScrollView using DragGesture?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to mimic `ScrollView` behaviour in my own custom component.

The thing I'm having trouble with is scroll animation. As far I understand I can use `predictedEndTranslation` object to get the predicted position of the drag gesture. But I don't know which easing function I should use to mimic default `ScrollView` easing.

Here is my code

```
struct ViewContent: View {
    @State var offsetY: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        View {

        }
        .offset(y: offsetY)
        .gesture(
          DragGesture()
            .onChange { value in
                offsetY = value.translation.height
            }
            .onEnded { value in 
                let nextScrollPosition = value.predictedEndTranslation.height

                withAnimation(???) { // What easing to use?
                    offsetY = nextScrollPosition
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58708206/12299030?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `.spring()` as this preset animation will get you the closes to the generic scrollview animation.

```
withAnimation(.spring()) { // User .spring()
    offsetY = nextScrollPosition
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use this `.spring()` but wasn't sure if this easing is  the best one

Comment: Can I ask why you cannot use a regular scrollview?

Comment: I would like to implement snap interval (stop at the closest row or column, not at the middle or somewhere else) which is not supported in default ScrollView.