# How to fill SwiftUI's VStack from bottom to top with items

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have been searching but could not find a way.

I would like to fill VStack view from bottom to top.
When a Text view added as a child to VStack for example it is places at the top.
I wanted to add it to the bottom of screen and second one on top of the first one.

```
@State var items: [Int] = [0]

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        
        Button(action: {
            
            items.append( items.count + 1)
            
        }){
            Text("Add")
        }
        
        
        
        ScrollView() {
            ForEach(0..<items.count, id: \.self) { index in
                VStack(spacing:5) {
                    Text(String(items[index]))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you get on top of screen;

1

2

What I want at the bottom of screen;

2

1

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58708206/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi Not exactly, it is more about scrolling to the wanted item. I want items ordered from bottom to top of screen. I have no problem with going to wanted items in scroll.

Comment: Ok, provide minimal reproducible example of use-case, because it is not clear what do you mean by "add" and where/how this should be used. VStack does not relates to screen, it just shrinks around content, and it is not collection so you cannot just "add" anything to it. In short your question is not clear.

Comment: @Asperi I added! a sample code as you can see when you touch add it is adding! numbers from top to bottom not bottom to the top which I want.

Comment: I don't see how this differs from a reference provided above, just instead of items.append use items.insert(.. at: 0) there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by applying `rotationEffect` to your `ScrollView` and its inner content.

```
@State var items: [Int] = [0]

var body: some View {
    
    HStack {
        
        Button(action: {
            //Insert Items at 0 position to add content from bottom to top side
            items.insert(items.count, at: 0)
        }){
            Text("Add")
        }
        
        
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {

                ForEach(0..<items.count, id: \.self) { index in

                    Text(String(items[index])).padding(.vertical,5)

                }.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180)) //After rotating scrollview, now rotate your inner content to upright position.

        }.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -180)) //Rotate scrollview to bottom side
    }
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI i works so weird or I have got used to UIView  too much.

Answer (score -1):

How's this?

```swift
ScrollView {
  VStack(spacing: 5) {
    Spacer()
    ForEach(items.map(String.init).reversed(), id: \.self) { item in
      Text(item)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the main problem how to place them on screen reversing just item order was not the issue @Skwiggs

Comment: I've edited the answer with an extra Spacer(), have a look @Hope